# I have the below code that does not seem to work at all ..I keep getting: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I was tring to create a simple datepicker control using JQuery, but i was getting that error.
I have no clue why i am getting that error. Trying from 3 hrs but couldn't find the solution.
Can anyone plz help me with this.
Here is my code which i placed in masterpage.

```
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/DevExMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<link href="~/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" ></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>    
   </head>
```

this is the code i am using in my source file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
        });

    </script>
<p>
 <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                           </p>
</asp:Content>
```

I dont know what the problem is but when i am trying the same code without a master page it is working fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET could be renamaing the id of datepicker1.

After the DOM is ready, you could try to get the runtime id and setting to a js var:

```
textboxDatePick = '<%= datepicker1.ClientID %>';
```

Then in your scipt change  $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
to: $("#" + textboxDatePick).datepicker();

Comment: in thinking about this more. you may want to try for fun: is to give a class name to the datepicker1 and use the jqeury class selector instead of the id selector.  that way you would need less code.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker1" CssClass="ui-datePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> then in script $(".ui-datePicker").datepicker();